# Find a formula for solution of $dx/dt=ax+g(t), x(0)=c$ given the solution to another differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a non-autonomous equation of the form $dx/dt = ax + g(t).$ If $x(t)$ is a solution, show that $y(t) = x(t) e^{−at}$ satisfies the equation $dy/dt = g(t) e^{−at}.$

Now I am told that $dy/dt = g(t) e^{−at}$ has a solution of the form $y(t) = \int g(s) e^{−as}ds$ and can use this to find a solution to $dx/dt=ax+g(t), x(0)=c$.

How to work this out?

Comment: Well, have you tried to work it out?  For example, the first part, that $y(t)$ defined in that way indeed satisfies the given equation $y'(t)= g(t) e^{-at}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = ax(t) + g(t) \tag{1}$

and

$y(t) = x(t)e^{-at}, \tag{2}$

then

$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{dt} e^{-at} + x(t) \dfrac{de^{-at}}{dt}$
$=\dfrac{dx}{dt} e^{-at} + x(t) (-ae^{-at})$
$= \dfrac{dx}{dt} e^{-at} -ax(t)e^{-at}; \tag{3}$

now using (1) in the right of (3) we have

$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = (ax(t) + g(t))e^{-at} - ax(t)e^{-at}$
$= g(t)e^{-at}, \tag{4}$

as required.  ***QED.***

The preceeding remarks answer the first question posed in the text of the post.  As for the second section, it is clear that the equation

$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = g(t)e^{-at} \tag{5}$

has a solution of the form

$y(t) = \int g(s)e^{-as} ds; \tag{6}$

indeed, it follows from (5) that $y(t)$ is an anti-derivative of $g(t)e^{-at}$.  If we integrate (5) over the inrerval $(0, t)$ we obtain

$y(t) - y(0) = \int_0^t \dfrac{dy(s)}{ds} ds$
$= \int_0^t g(s)e^{-as} ds, \tag{7}$

or

$y(t) = y(0) + \int_0^t g(s)e^{-as} ds; \tag{8}$

from (2) we find

$x(t) = e^{at}y(t)$
$= e^{at}(y(0) + \int_0^t g(s) e^{-as} ds); \tag{9}$

taking the derivative of $x(t)$ using the Leibniz rule for products yields

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}$
$= ae^{at}(y(0) + \int_0^t g(s) e^{-as} ds)$
$+ e^{at} \dfrac{d}{dt} \int_0^t g(s) e^{-as} ds$
$= ax(t) + e^{at}g(t)e^{-at} = ax(t) + g(t), \tag{10}$

showing $x(t)$ as defined by (9) satisfies (1).  Inspecting (9), we see that

$x(0) = y(0); \tag{11}$

thus taking $y(0) = c$ yields $x(0) = c$ as well.  Note we have used (5), (6) to find a solution to (1) satisfying (11).

Answer (score 1):

Hint, try to transform the original equation, by multiplying the $x(t)$ function with another function $\mu(t)$ in order to eliminate the in-homogeneous term $g(t)$.

Then $\mu(t)$ would have a specific relation to $g(t)$. This is called the [*method of integrating factor* in ODEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dot x = ax + g(t)$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\mu x ) = \dot \mu x + \mu \dot x = \dot \mu x + \mu ( ax + g(t)) =( \dot \mu + a \mu) x+ \mu g(t)   $$

choose $\mu(t) $ to make the coefficient of $x(t)$ vanish

$$\dot \mu + a \mu=0 \implies \mu (t) = e^{-at} $$

so now we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-at} x ) = e^{-at} g(t)   $$

Using the fundamental theorem of Calculus ...

$$x(t) = e^{at} \int _p^t e^{-as} g(s)ds   $$
where $p$ is the constant of integration which can be used to fix the initial conditions.

$$x(0)=c \implies x(t) = e^{at} \int _0^t e^{-as} g(s)ds + c e^{at}$$